# xcode iOS 6 Local notification with UIAlertView disappears after 5 or 6 seconds?

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios6, uialertview, localnotification

I am using a UILocalNotification to schedule a UIAlertView, which works great. However, in iOS 6 (possibly iOS 5) the notification disappears after 5 or 6 seconds.  Is there any way to prevent the notification from disappearing?

```
...
    UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
    notif.fireDate = [datePicker date];
    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    notif.alertBody = @"Blabla?";
    notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notif.hasAction = true;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
    [notif release];

...

- (void)showReminder:(NSString *)text {

    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Blabla?"
                                            message:text delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"YES"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Thanks!